# How to combine Azure Test Pland with Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Currently I am trying to using Azure Test Plans to manage all test cases, but I just found how to build / generate manual test cases. I also make some research about Pipeline and I just write some "hello world" test scripts and using Pipeline to automatically test the code. My question is: How could I combine TestPlans with Pipeline to make the test in pipeline recordable? Thank you so much!

[this is how the pipeline looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h06J.png)

[this is how the test code be checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9gCN.png)

Comment: Hi Lee, is there any update for this issue? Please check if my answer helps to resolve your puzzle,  feel free to let me know if you need further details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: How could I combine TestPlans with Pipeline to make
>   the test in pipeline recordable?

I'm a bit confused about what the `recordable` mean in your question. To combine TestPlan with Pipeline, you should configure the [Test Plan Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#set-up-your-environment). For example, set a build pipeline(build and generates the test binaries) and a release pipeline with test-related task in your Test Plan Settings.

The normal logic is:

```
A test plan containing your automated tests, which you have associated with automated test methods using Visual Studio 2017, or Visual Studio 2015 or earlier.

A Team Build pipeline that generates builds containing the test binaries.

The app to test. You can deploy the app as part of the build and release workflow and also use it for on-demand testing.
```

For more details please check [Run automated tests from test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#set-up-your-environment).